# solid scene gets transparent on render in Blender internal

Tags: transparency

I have a scene with transparent background without transparent objects. But while rendering all the scene gets half-transparent. 
Please, help to fix that!

[image]

Comment: Do you want the text to show? I'm not sure why the stars are transparent . . . the compositor seems to have no effect

Comment: The text is ok, I need stars not to be transparent, I did not told them to do so.

Comment: It seems to be result of alpha premultiply, render settings or something of that sort, but I don't know what to change.

Comment: I didn't see anything obvious. I normally use Cycles though, so maybe someone else will be able to spot it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options set up in a wrong way in your `.blend`, some aren't set at all.

(*To be honest, I couldn't see anything on your render in the beginning*)

1. There aren't options for rendering sky at all, because 2 Render
   Layers you have in Compositor mixed have Sky unckecked. Third
   one which has Sky checked (I assume it was created intentionally for
   sky rendering) isn't presented in Compositor. I enabled this layer
   (it's called "main") in `Render Layers` tab and disabled everything
   there except for the Sky option.

   [image: blender-internal_transparent-problem_1]
2. In `Particles settings` > `Render` scroll `Emitter` option hasn't
   been turned on, so you shouldn't see anything except for the stars,
   as text mesh is emitter for them and it wasn't told to be rendered.

   [image: blender-internal_transparent-problem_2]
3. Nodes. To see background and get rid of transparency eating final
   image one should add third layer (called  "main") and mix it with
   those present there already.

   [image: blender-internal_transparent-problem_3]

   I turned off backdrop here so it doesn't mess up nodes settings. I
   also changed background color so to see stars and text effects
   better.

   The final result:

   [image: final]

   *Update*

   To make everything untransparent with except for background you might want to  manipulate with alpha, using nodes setup as is shown on the next image:

   [image]

   Thus you'll have text and stars solid, and transparent background. At the  same  time I think you won't get any glare on the final image because of alpha  affecting on it.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Zak. I unchecked background layer to get scene with transparent alpha and then to combine it with a video. For demonstration I plased only stars just to show undesired transparency. I know that when having a background, scene renders without any surprised transparency, but I wanted to get the scene with non-transparent elements and transparent background. Finally I used cycles, but I still want to know what was that problem like, as internal works faster.

Comment: Well, this absolutely wasn't clear from your question. I think you wouldn't be able to achieve untransparent stars with glare *and* transparent background because glare won't have where to be rendered and thus be shown. For more details see my answer update. Also I didn't get why Cycles is mentioned - your scene is in BI thus I used BI.

Comment: Sorry for unclear post, Mr Zak. 
You and I don't see any ways to render the scene with transparency for desired elements in BI, so I used cycles with its different settings and abilities and had success. It looks different a bit, but fits well.
Thank you for help!

Comment: It's ok. I'd like to add that if the last screenshot in my anwer isn't what you were searching for then you're right, I completely misunderstood the topic.

Comment: It's my fault - I gave you very few explanation and filled my blend with extensive information.
Finally the problem is bypassed, thank you for help! :)